# PHP $_GET with jQuery $.get call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am currently learning jQuery and php.

So I have this php file that gets called with a jQuery function (there is another call somewhere else in the script where a=chkPw):

```
$.get("checkName.php?a=chkUser&user=" + rqUser, function(data) { ... });
```

My problem is that the php script doesn't seem to get in the if(isset($_GET)) { } block. I have debugged the value that it returns (1), so I don't understand what's wrong! I have also debugged the value for $_GET['a'] and it is indeed 'chkUser'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

$users = array('bill' => 'ore', 'ted' => 'wood');

if (isset($_GET)) {

    if ($_GET['a'] == 'chkUser') {
        if (!array_key_exists($_GET['user'], $users)) {
            echo 'okay';
        } else {
            echo 'denied';
        }

    } elseif ($_GET['a'] == 'checkPw') {

        $user = $_GET['user'];
        $pw = $_GET['pw'];
        $i = 0;

        // get username id
        foreach (array_keys($users) as $value) {
            if ($value == $user) {
                $user = $users[i];
            }
            i++;
        }

        // match pw
        if ($pw == $user) {
            echo 'okay';
        } else {
            echo 'denied'
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: When a=chkUser, it's supposed to see if the chkUser exists as a key in $users. As long as I can get that to work, I can figure out the rest.

But my problem is that the php doesn't get into the if (isset($_GET)) { } block for some reason.

Comment: I recommend not building your $.get URL like that...try something like `$.get('checkName.php',{'a':'chkUser','user':rqUser}, function ...`

Comment: var_dump( $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST );

Comment: Isnt it just a typo in your check ? it seems to me that you are using two different "actions" chkUser and chkPw but in your check you are assuming that you get "chkUser" and "checkPw" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey it seems to me that this is working:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $.get("checkNames.php?a=chkUser&user=bill", function(data) { console.log(data) });
    $.get("checkNames.php?a=chkPass&user=bill&pw=ore", function(data) { console.log(data)                 });

</script>

<?php

$users = array('bill' => 'ore', 'ted' => 'wood');

if (isset($_GET["a"])) {

  if ($_GET["a"] == 'chkUser') {
    if (!array_key_exists($_GET['user'], $users)) {
        echo 'okay';
    } else {
        echo 'denied';
    }

  } elseif ($_GET["a"] == 'chkPass') {

    $user = $_GET['user'];
    $pw = $_GET['pw'];
    if(array_key_exists($user, $users))
    {
        if($users[$user] == $pw)
        {
            echo "okay";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "denied";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "denied";
    }

  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Awesome! I don't know what I was doing with loops and crazy things. I am not used to using maps, heh.

It does work! and I actually found the original reason for my script breaking - a silly misspelled variable... I am not used to having to type $ in front of them!

I feel embarrassed. Thanks to everyone though!

Comment: Well i saw the mistakes when i copied your code but thought it would be more helpful with a working sample :)

Answer (score 0):

With a url like www.something.com/index.html?a=1 
This code does in fact work on testing:

```
$users = array('bill' => 'ore', 'ted' => 'wood');

if (isset($_GET)) {
echo 'something';
}
```

Try commenting it down further to let us know if it is the whole whole elseif or just a part of it

Comment: Right, it returns 'okay' if the key doesn't exist. It means the username is free to be taken.

Comment: Alright, I see what you're doing. I thought you were validating :( Anyways, what does your get url look like in firebug?

Comment: I have narrowed it down to a problem with the

        } elseif ($_GET['a'] == 'checkPw') {

It does work if I delete that elseif block...

Answer (score 0):

Try this if statement instead of current

```
if (count($_GET) > 0) {
    // existing code
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET)){
  ...
}
?>
```

To be sure about the GET payload use var_dump($_GET)